# android create a popup screen for showing help on a page that extends view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-dialog

I am creating an application which using custom view and i have designed the layout using a  class that extends view.

Now i have a help icon on that view which have to popup on click.I have tried dialog window but i need a window without title and border.

I have checked some games and they are using what exactly i need. Anybody  can suggest a better solution?

here is my sample  code to get help button

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
        int action = me.getAction();
        if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ){
            x = me.getX();
            y = me.getY();
if (x >= helpButtonX && x < (helpButtonX +help.getWidth())&&
 y >= helpButtonY && y <     helpButtonY + help.getHeight() ) 
  {
           // code toshow popup
   }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can create a custom dialog with the layout designed by you.

For that simply create a dialog and set the layout by using `setContentView()` method.

For example:

```
 Dialog dialog = new Dialog(myActivity.this);
 dialog.setContentView(R.layout.myDialogLayout);
 dialog.setTitle("");
 dialog.setCancelable(true);
 dialog.show();
```

Comment: Yes i have tried that.But i need an overlay popup not a custom dialog

Comment: @ileaf you should have posted example snap :(

Comment: @ileaf yes its possible with the same way i have mentioned above.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10695/discussion-between-i-leaf-and-paresh-mayani)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a hidden View that is set using relativeLayout over the other elements in the layout.xml. when the user clicks the help button, the visibility is changed to visible and the View is shown. YOu can then set an onclick listener on the View that when they touch it, it will be hidden again.

Comment: He doesnt want to use a dialog, this is another option that would be easy to code.

Comment: i don't have a xml file only a view created by code. Also i am confused about how the ontouchEvent will get the layout xml resource id

Comment: why dont you create your layout in xml? and then setContentView on the Activity? that will allow you to easily create the GUI

Comment: i am using a custom view class as content view like public class TestPage extends View{}

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a PopupWindow with custom layout.

Add this code in your `{//Code to show popup}`

```
//Get a layout inflator
LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
//Initialize a popup window with custom xml view - R.layout.popup.xml
View popupView = li.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
final PopupWindow pW = new PopupWindow(popupView,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

To dismiss it use `pW.dismiss()` wherever you want

Try this: http://android-er.blogspot.jp/2012/03/example-of-using-popupwindow.html